# Hide div onClick with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toggle, slideup

I have a [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/fS5gq/) of a script that allows me to show and hide content on my site. It is working perfectly.

However, **when I click on a link to show the content and then click it again to hide it, it re-opens it.** I need it to fully hide when clicked whilst on show ('active') status.

Can anyone explain how to fix this?

Thank you.

**CODE:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 $('.showscroll').bind('click', 'h2, h3', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();

   $(this).toggleClass('active');
   $('.newboxes2').slideUp().delay(200);
   $(this).find('.newboxes2').slideToggle();

               if($(this).is('.active') ) {
                       $(this).find('img.small').attr('src', '/wp-content/themes/boilerplate/images/image_corner_btn_onstate.png');
               } else {
                       $(this).find('img.small').attr('src', '/wp-content/themes/boilerplate/images/image_corner_btn_offstate.png');
               }
   if (this.id === 'service29') {
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(this).find('h2').offset().top
    }, 1000);
                }

 });

});
```

Comment: Don't call `.slideUp` *and* `.slideToggle`

Comment: Hi Explosion Pills, many thanks for the reply. Can you tell me how I should update my code so it will close when clicked?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will toggle properly if you call only `.slideToggle`.  With the call to `.slideUp` each time, it will slide up when it is visible and then immediately slide down because it's being toggled again.  It slides down the first time because `.slideUp` doesn't make it visible.

If you want to hide all the other elements, you can use `.not` to exclude the current "shown" element.

http://jsfiddle.net/fS5gq/3/

Comment: Perfect!! Out of interest, I only want to display ONE div at one time. So if I click 'Test 2', it closes 'Test 1'.  That's how it worked previously. Are you able to modify your jsfiddle to do this? Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: I understand now.  You just have to slide up all the other ones: http://jsfiddle.net/fS5gq/3/

Comment: Wow - you're fast!! Thanks. I will try right now and report back. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: That did the job. Are you OK to update your answer to include that new jsfiddle and I will accept. Thank you so, so much. You've saved the day.

Answer (score 1):

Try this remove `$('.newboxes2').slideUp().delay(200);`

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

 $('.showscroll').bind('click', 'h2, h3', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();

   $(this).toggleClass('active');       
   $(this).find('.newboxes2').slideToggle();

               if($(this).is('.active') ) {
                       $(this).find('img.small').attr('src', '/wp-content/themes/boilerplate/images/image_corner_btn_onstate.png');
               } else {
                       $(this).find('img.small').attr('src', '/wp-content/themes/boilerplate/images/image_corner_btn_offstate.png');
               }
   if (this.id === 'service29') {
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(this).find('h2').offset().top
    }, 1000);
                }

 });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fS5gq/4/

Comment: Many thanks for your reply, Nandu. Explosion Pills has answered correctly above. I'll check out your fiddle right now.